# iterating over a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I put this dataframe as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['china','canda','usa' ], 'value':[1000, 850, 1100], 'fact':[1000,200,850]})
df.index=df['country']
df = df.drop('country', axis=1)
```

I want to iterate over the GDP of each country and into this iteration I want to create a new column that would be full of 1 or 0 in function of a condition:

```
for x in df['value']:
    if x > 900:
        df['answer']=1
    else:
        df['answer']=0
```

I would expected a column with the following values:

```
[1,0,1]
```

Because Canada has a value lower than 900.

But instead I have a column full of ones.

What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it is: I want to iterate over the value

Answer (score 1):

It can be even done without iterating over each row using:

```
df['answer'] = df['value'].apply(lambda value: 1 if value > 900 else 0)
```

**EDIT** You are assigning `df['answer']` to some value. The last value is *1* that is why it applies *1* to the entire ***answer*** column and not a particular row.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df["answer"] = np.where(df["value"]> 900, 1,0)
```

Or

```
df["answer"] = (df["value"]> 900).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
         value  fact    answer
country         
china     1000  1000    1
canda     850   200     0
usa       1100  850     1
```

**whats wrong with your code**

When you do `df['answer']=1`, the expression assign 1 to all the rows in `answer` column.

So last evaluated value is assigned to that column

Comment: @ilegionpy accept and upvote the answer if it helped